# Is there a way I can get list of all exception messages that SSIS can raise

Tags: exception, ssis

I need to convert SSIS exception messages into user understandable messages. Are these messages defined any where?

How can I download [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345164%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) list of messages into my sql table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a macro to build it out for 2008 error messages. Is something like this what you're looking for? [SSIS error list in tabular format](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssis-error-list-in-tabular-format.html)

Comment: Yes I was looking for the same. Thank you